# Multidimensional vectors in rust, segfaulting?

Tags: multidimensional-array, struct, rust

In C# I could do something like this

```
class Map {    
    public Tile[, ,] Location = new Tile[6, 256, 256];
}
```

and later access any Tile element with something like `Location[2, 40, 20]`

I'm trying to make similar type of structure in Rust but I'm finding the syntax a bit odd. I did come up with this, but it segfaulted with large vector sizes (ran out of stack?):

```
use tile::Tile // Simple struct with a few Point properties

pub struct Map {
    location: [[[Tile, ..256], ..256], ..6],
}

pub impl Map {
    fn new() -> Map {
        Map {
            // assuming empty_tile is a Tile I've just created
            location: [[[empty_tile, ..256], ..256], ..6]
        }
    }
}
```

Am I going about this incorrectly? It ran really slowly and large sizes segfaulted. Perhaps there's a better way to store a three dimensional space of tiles (layer, width, height)?

edit: this is before I even try and make those Tiles mutable

Comment: Did you try a small MD-vector, to see if the problem is that it's too large?

Comment: Are you segfaulting in rustc, or when trying to run the produced executable?

Comment: Corey: When I try to run the executable.

Comment: It seems you've hit a compiler bug: https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/6555

Comment: @LennyStackOverflow, it is a bug, that's not the *actual* bug here. (I was mistaken in opening it, Rust should allocate enough stack for the struct, but isn't in this case.)

Comment: @dbaupp: i was refering to thestinger's comment in your issue. Should have made this more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[[[Tile, ..256], ..256], ..6]` is stack allocated, and it's going to be probably ~60MB large. Try `~[~[~[Tile, ..256], ..256], ..6]`, which is an owned pointer (allocated on the send heap, owned pointers can be sent across tasks)

Comment: How do I then initialise the vector?

    Map {            
        location: ~[~[~[empty_tile, ..256], ..256], ..6]
    }

Comment: @boden, `vec::from_elem(6, vec::from_elem(256, vec::from_elem(256, empty_tile)))`

Comment: it should still be fine to put a vector that big on the stack, although probably not a good idea in most cases performance-wise

Comment: Also, to add to this, you can also do `~([[[ empty_tile, ..256], .. 256], ..6])`, to heap-allocate the fixed size structure, instead of also heap-allocating each element. Or have `new` return `~Map`, and use `~Map { ... }`.